# Using password protected API in python

Tags: python-3.x, api

I'm having trouble working with an api. I was given a password and the header (x-app-id) I was given little documentation on the api but below it is shown how to retrieve the data using curl (from documentation):

```
curl -X GET "https://r6db.com/api/v2/players?
name=Bomb&platform=ps4&exact=true" -H "accept: application/json" -H "x-app-
id: password"
```

Above returns information on a player named 'Bomb' on the platform 'ps4' relating to the game Rainbow six siege. exact = true means tat the name has to be exact.

Can't give password for security reasons. Here is my try at replicating above in python going off another post I saw

```
import json 
import requests
URL = "https://r6db.com/api/v2/players?name=Bomb&platform=ps4&exact=true"
KEY = "password"
headers  = {"x-app-id": "application/json"}
params = {
  "a-app-id": KEY
}
resp = requests.post(URL + "login/", headers = headers, 
data=json.dumps(params))

if resp.status_code != 200:
    print('error: ' + str(resp.status_code))
else:
    print('Success')
```

Needless to say it doesn't work (it outputs error 404) which probably means I haven't even managed to get x-app-id as the header, any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a bit of a mess when passing the parameters with the module `requests`

There are two things to pass in the headers: `accept: application/json` and `x-app-id: password` and you are doing that fine in curl.

But in python you are passing the header `"x-app-id": "application/json"` (makes not much sense) and try to pass `"a-app-id": KEY}` as a parameter, not as a header.

If you pass it as a parameter, it will be included in your url in the form of `https://r6db.com/api/v2/players?name=Bomb&platform=ps4&exact=true&a-app-id=KEY` and that is not what you want.

You already know how to pass headers in python, so you only have to pass the right ones: Pass `accept: application/json` and `x-app-id: password`

If I got your description right, I think you don´t have to pass data parameters.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response I was attempting to get it working after your comment I'm not sure if this is exactly what u were saying but this worked `import json 
import requests
URL = "https://r6db.com/api/v2/players?name=Bomb113&platform=ps4&exact=true"
headers  = {"x-app-id": "application/json"}
resp = requests.get(URL , headers = headers, auth=('x-app-id','password'))
if resp.status_code != 200:
    print('error: ' + str(resp.status_code))
else:
    print('Success')
    print(resp.text)`